# OAuthClientRequest Proxy Server

Tags: java, oauth, proxy

I am using OAuthClientRequest to get the access token based on TOTP in JAVA 8.

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                    .tokenLocation(tokenUrl)
                    .setGrantType(GrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                    .setClientId(clientId)
                    .setClientSecret(TOTP)
                    .buildBodyMessage();
```

I am getting server connection timeout issue whenever I use my company's network but when I use non-company network I get the proper response.
I know it's the proxy which is causing the problem.
I don't know how to set proxy server property for OAuthClientRequest ?

I have set proxy for HttpPost request and it worked but don't how to set for OAuthClientRequest ?